# Ruby model output id as object oid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, mongoid

My ruby model, like so:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :birthdate, type: Date

  validates :first_name, :birthdate, :presence => true

end
```

outputs an object like so:

```
{
_id: {
$oid: "522884c6c4b4ae5c76000001"
},
birthdate: null,
first_name: null,
}
```

My backbone project has no idea how to handle _id.$oid.

I found this article and code:

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/355/files

```
module Moped
  module BSON
    class ObjectId
      alias :to_json :to_s
    end
  end
end
```

I have no idea where to put this, and how to invoke it on the model output, so I tried inside:

/config/initializers/secret_token.rb

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and have no idea how to proceed, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: That `Moped::BSON::ObjectId` monkey patch can be placed anywhere (an initializer does sound like a good spot, though you should make a new initializer for just this code) and it should work.  After you added that and restarted the rails server, did it work? What happened instead of what you expected?

Comment: Please, if you use the syntax construct `alias`, then use it properly: `alias to_json to_s`. If you want to use a method where you actually have to pass symbols, use alias_method: `alias_method :to_json, :to_s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For guys using Mongoid 4+ use this,

```
module BSON
  class ObjectId
    alias :to_json :to_s
    alias :as_json :to_s
  end
end
```

[Reference](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/354)

Answer (score 33):

Iterating on Kirk's answer:

In Mongoid 4 the Moped’s BSON implementation has been removed in favor of the MongoDB bson gem, so the correct version for Mongoid 4 users is:

```
module BSON
  class ObjectId
    def to_json(*args)
      to_s.to_json
    end

    def as_json(*args)
      to_s.as_json
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked as well, just don't forget to restart your server and reset any caching if your API's are cached (had to figure that out the hard way)...

Comment: This worked for me: If you add the `alias :to_json :to_s` solution as specified in previous answers, you'll get the following error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Answer (score 7):

What you should do is place this in the initializer folder, create a file like this:

/config/initializers/mongoid.rb

```
module Moped
  module BSON
    class ObjectId
      alias :to_json :to_s
      alias :as_json :to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do I need to define a way to include that or does it automatically include initializers? I created the file and its still outputting as _id.$oid

Comment: hi @azz0r i forget to add the alias on the as_json method too. Try that code. About the initializer folder, rails runs through all files inside config/initializers/. and run them all.

Answer (score 3):

Aurthur's answer worked for everything except rabl. If you are using rabl the attributes :id will throw an exception. The following code will be compatible with rabl.

```
module Moped
  module BSON
    class ObjectId
      def to_json(*args)
        to_s.to_json
      end

      def as_json(*args)
        to_s.as_json
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For more information, see the github issue https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/337

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better answer

```
require "bson"

class Jbuilder < JbuilderProxy

  def _extract_method_values(object, *attributes)
    attributes.each do |key|
      value = object.public_send(key)

      if value.is_a? ::BSON::ObjectId
        value = value.to_s
      end

      _set_value key, value
    end
  end
end
```