# How to get $oid hash value as string with mongo aggregate framework?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection with objects with a json output like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "53107ed2e6fb449fa641b903"
  },
  "title": "myBook"
}
```

But I would like to get this:

```
{
  "_id": "53107ed2e6fb449fa641b903",
  "title": "myBook"
}
```

I have tried with dot notation and $project but it doesn't work:

```
db.books.aggregate({
  $project: {
    _id: "$_id.oid",
    title: 1 
  }
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby model output id as object oid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646223/ruby-model-output-id-as-object-oid)

Comment: You want _id as string not ObjectID. Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your aggregate query syntax is incorrect.  Try this:

```
db.books.aggregate([{$project:{_id:"$_id.oid", title:1}}])
```

Also, in the input json, you have a '$' prefix for the oid (i.e, "$oid").  That's illegal in MongoDB.

Comment: I that is the whole point of his question. How to do this with an $oid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059986/how-to-project-objectid-to-string-value-in-mongodb-aggregate