# how to $project ObjectId to string value in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there an operator I could use in **aggregate** function to get a string instead of ObjectId in response?

```
db.something.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "property": { "$exists": true } } },
  { "$project": { "stringId": "$_id.???" } }
])
```

Comment: No there isn't. The aggregation framework does not re-cast any data types ( except to string from numeric via `$substr` and numeric to Date or Date to numeric is basically possible with trickery ). Why would you think this is needed anyway? It's fairly simple in most languages to write the `ObjectId` value as a string anyway.

Comment: @BlakesSeven There is always why :) Because of simplicity. Of course you can post process it. But it would be nice if I could just pass the result to other service/party who requires plain string. ...

Comment: Well like I said, with most languages the BSON is just cast to local types. And for "most" languages, there is no work at all required to simply output as a string. Personally I prefer the extended JSON output form i.e `{ "$oid": "56ea9e8bb1e015d13b376db5" }` since at least that lets a remote client know that the data is indeed an `ObjectId` so it can parse and cast correctly itself. That's a good thing, especially considering that storage is **half** the bytes of the string length.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Mongodb **4.0** has introduced [**`$toString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation operator. So, Now you can easily convert ObjectId to string

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

OR vice versa using [**`$toObjectId`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $toObjectId: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: How about in Mongodb version 3.6?

Comment: @Charlie No you can't. You have to upgrade to 4.0 and that's what always been intresting about the new versions.

Comment: But how to do this in version 3.9 ?

Comment: @Boat Mongodb has not introduced any 3.9 version. Are you talking about any driver version? or mongodb 3.6.9?

Comment: @Ashh I was referring to mongodb 3.6.9

Comment: @Boat Then have a look at second comment.

Answer (score 11):

There is no Direct Operator in aggregate function to get String from ObjectId.

After version 2.6 You can use `ObjectId.toString()` method to convert your ObjectId to string. First you match and project your ObjectID. Then you can convert this object ID to string by using `ObjectID.toString()`.

```
db.something.aggregate([{"$match":{'property': {$exists:true}}},{"$project":{"_id":1}}])
```

And then use resulting Object and get the string as response using `ObjectID.tostring()`

Edit: You can access the str attribute of the object id using

```js
ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea").str
```

source: [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#access-the-hexadecimal-string)

Answer (score -17):

You can do it inline using the `$concat` operator:

```
db.something.aggregate(
    [
        { $match :
            { 'property' :
                { $exists:true }
            }
        },
        { $project:
            { stringId:
                { $concat: [ ObjectId().str ] }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: For me, this doesn't make "stringId" the ObjectId of the record.  It makes it a stringified version of a brand new ObjectId.  In particular, it's the same value for all the documents returned.  So I don't think this is right.

Comment: lol fail ......