# Convert ObjectID to String in mongo Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, robo3t

I'm in this scenario right now:
I have a collection X:

```
{
  _id:ObjectId('56edbb4d5f084a51131dd4c6'),
  userRef:ObjectId('56edbb4d5f084a51131dd4c6'),
  serialNumber:'A123123',
  ...
}
```

I need to aggregate all documents, grouping them by the userRef + serialNumber, so I'm trying to use concat like this:

```
$group: {
        _id: {
            '$concat': ['$userRef','-','$serialNumber']
        },
       ...
```

So basically in my aggregation in MongoDB, I need to group documents by the concatenation of a ObjectId and a string. However, It seems that $concat only accepts strings as parameters:

```
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {

    "errmsg" : "exception: $concat only supports strings, not OID",
    "code" : 16702,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Is there a way to convert an ObjectId to a String within an aggregation expression?

**EDIT**:

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059986/how-to-project-objectid-to-string-value-in-mongodb-aggregate) is related, but I the solution doesn't fit my problem. (Specially because I can't use ObjectId.toString() during the aggregation)

Indeed I couldn't find any ObjectId().toString() operation in Mongo's documentation, but I wonder if there's any tricky thing that can be done in this case.

Comment: Maybe `_id: [ $userRef, $serialNumber ]` works? It will not give you a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do what I wanted, so instead, I created a MapReduce function that, in the end, generated the keys the way I wanted to (concatenating other keys).

At the end, it looked something like this:

```
db.collection('myCollection').mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(
            this.userRef.str + '-' + this.serialNumber , {
                count: 1,
                whateverValue1:this.value1,
                whateverValue2:this.value2,
                ...
            }
        )
    },
    function(key, values) {
       var reduce = {}
       .... my reduce function....
        return reduce
    }, {
        query: {
            ...filters_here....
        },
        out: 'name_of_output_collection'
    }
);
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is the code you wrote ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur see if this helps. I edited the comment

Comment: Thank you for your answer actually i was reading about aggregation and map reduce and there i found that map reduce is a lot times slower then aggregation thatisy i thought about to tell you it would be better if you coulf do this in agregation.

Comment: Yeah I know... But I never found a solution using aggregation :/

Answer (score 9):

Now you can try with  [**`$toString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation which simply 
converts ObjectId to string

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "userRef": { "$toString": "$userRef" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
      "_id": { "$concat": ["$userRef", "-", "$serialNumber"] }
    }}
])
```

You can check the output [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yhhe83SKiJf)

Comment: Is this a new type of aggregation?

Comment: Nice! I will test it out! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @AndréPerazzi I have posted the link as well... You can check it out...

Comment: This is available from version 4 of MongoDB. So, if you are on some lower version, you won't be able to do this

Comment: @ankit-kumar-sharma 's answer is much better, using $toString inside the $contact instead of in a seperate stage first

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use **$toString** to apply $concat in aggregation on ObjectIDs in the following way -

```
$group: {
    '_id': {
        '$concat': [
            { '$toString' : '$userRef' },
            '-',
            { '$toString' : '$serialNumber'}
        ]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to resolve it by using an Array which contains both fields:

```
{$project:{newkey:['$userRef','$serialNumber']},{$match:{newkey:{$in:filterArray}}}}
```

this may match the data with both fields to the filter. Please notice that the data in the newkey array should have the same data type with the filterArray elements.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$substr` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/#exp._S_substr to cast any object to string before `$concat`.

This is a sample of code that's working for me.

```
group_id_i['_id'] = {
    '$concat' => [
        { '$substr' => [ {'$year' => '$t'}, 0, -1] }, '-',
        { '$substr' => [ {'$month' => '$t'}, 0, -1] }, '-',
        { '$substr' => [ {'$dayOfMonth' => '$t'}, 0, -1] }
    ]
}
```

Where `t` is DateTime field, this aggregation returns data like so.

```
{
    "_id" => "28-9-2016",
    "i" => 2
}
```