# MongoDB 3.6 how to convert string to Object Id

Tags: mongodb, lookup, objectid

I am working with MongoDB 3.6. I'm trying to do an aggregation $lookup as below.

$lookup

```
{
  from: 'm_mtr',
  localField: 'mtdid',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'mm'
}
```

This doesn't work for me as 'mtdid' is a string with values like '5bdbe5bcff10z046fcf8f04a'and '_id' is an Object Id field with values like 'ObjectId('5bdbe5bcff10z046fcf8f04a')'.

Is there a way to convert string to ObjectId? I know this is possible in Mongodb 4.0. Unfortunately I don't have an option of using anything other than 3.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to $project ObjectId to string value in mongodb aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059986/how-to-project-objectid-to-string-value-in-mongodb-aggregate)

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891511/mongodb-concat-int-and-string

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose, you can use this function:

```
let id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5bdbe5bcff10z046fcf8f04a');
```

Comment: Thanks! can ObjectId take a string variable as the parameter?

Comment: No. you need to convert string to ObjectId first.

// Get the objectID type
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var idString = '5bdbe5bcff10z046fcf8f04a';
collection.findOne({_id: new ObjectID(idString)}, console.log)  // ok
collection.findOne({_id: idString}, console.log)  // wrong! callback gets undefined