# How to convert MongoDB UUID to string in MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I am converting MongoDB UUID to string in MongoDB projection query using $toString, its giving the following error:
"Unsupported conversion from binData to string in $convert with no onError value"

Can anyone suggest a solution, please?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? your query perfectly works for me. More reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059986/how-to-project-objectid-to-string-value-in-mongodb-aggregate?rq=1

Comment: I am using MongoDB 4.0.6 version.

Comment: I was tried this solution, but not able to figure out is implementation inside the MongoDB aggregation query. Moreover, I need to convert UUID to string using MongoDB aggregation query

Comment: Any particular reason to convert UUID to string?

Comment: Its needed for angular web application transactions with MongoDB using Asp.Net core web API.

Comment: I think you'll need to convert your UUIDs to strings outside of your aggregation query. It's just binary data to MongoDB.

Comment: @RamakantShukla Try converting UUID string in C# code.